# 80192ee7 error during AzureAD MDM enrollment

Tags: azure-active-directory

Anyone familiar with error 80192ee7 while enrolling device?

After entering account in Join this device to Azure Active Directory, I can verify "Terms and conditions" page, and after that process crash and I get this error message.

Tnx In advance for answer.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to some issue with the DNS service running on the machine, check if you are able to resolve to enrollment.manage.microsoft.com site.

These are mostly seen if you manage your own DNS and when the machine is not able to reach that site for some reason, I would start with DNS troubleshooting towards this.